# Spring 3 JmsTemplate in out queue different

Tags: spring, jms, jmstemplate

org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate only supports
one queue using defaultDestination.....

what do I need to do when I have different in and out bound queue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question - yes, `JmsTemplate` only provides one *default* destination.

However, all of the various send/receive methods on `JmsTemplate` are overloaded with versions that allow you to specify a different destination.

For example, as well as `send(MessageCreator)` there is also `send(Destination, MessageCreator)`. All of the methods are overloaded like this.